# Frequency() with arrays: adds an element to return arrays

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I'm using the following formula as named formula (via name manager). It is then used in a larger sumproduct(). The goal is to ensure that with an array calculation, the calculation is only made once for certain groups of rows (e.g. you have the same data repeated accross many rows for category A. I only need to know how many people are in category A once).

```
=IF(FREQUENCY(IF(LEN(tdata[reportUUID])>0,MATCH(tdata[reportUUID],
 tdata[reportUUID],0),0),IF(LEN(tdata[reportUUID])>0,MATCH(tdata[reportUUID],
 tdata[reportUUID],0),0))>0,TRUE)
```

Let's step through the results one by one with the evaluate formula in Excel. Sorry for the screenshot, but Excel doesn't allow to copy actual steps with real data....

In order of steps:

[image: Step1, 6 items in array]

[image: Still 6 items]

[image: Still 6]

[image: Still 6, all good]

[image: Who ordered that 7th items at the end?]

In the last image, there's now a 7th item in my array. I only have 6 row of data, hence why for the previous steps I only had 6 items in the array, as was expect.

This is messing up my calculations, because the return array from this function gets multiplied by others arrays which all have 6 items (or whatever is the number of data rows I have).

What is this 7th item, and how can I either get ride of it or prevent it from return errors?

I did try to wrap some formula into iferror() or ifna(), however it doesn't feel clean. I feel this might backfire and isn't a strong way to handle this. I rather take it at the source....

EDIT: For example of use with other arrays:

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(--IFERROR(((tdata[_isVisible]=1)*(f_uniqueUUIDfactor),0))}
```

Where f_uniqueUUIDfactor is the formula from the initial post. tdata[_isVisible]=1 is used as a way to filter data on the dashboard (e.g. through dropdown, the users can set ranges for dates, and with VBA I hide the rows in the raw data NOT within the range).

The point is that sumproduct() ends up multipliying each raw data row thogheter as 0 & 1 s, so that only those meeting all the criterias get returned.  The IFERROR() above is the workaround for the extra array element introduced by frequency(). It works as is, but if a cleaner way exists I'd prefer that. I would also be keen on understanding why that elements get added.

Comment: Re "...because the return array from this function gets multiplied by others arrays which all have 6 items...", could we see those other arrays? I will add a generic answer in the meantime, though a lot depends on what further manipulations you are intending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good example of why it is preferable to use multiple, recursive `IF` statements when evaluating arrays over multiple criteria, rather than form the product of those arrays.

Firstly, though, before coming to the reason for that statement, I should point out a few minor technical inaccuracies/flaws with your construction also.

1) By including a *value_if_false* clause in your constructions being passed as `FREQUENCY`'s *data_array* and *bins_array* parameters, you are risking incorrect results, since zero is a valid numerical to be considered by `FREQUENCY`, whereas a Boolean `FALSE` (which would be the equivalent entry in the resulting array had you omitted the *value_if_false* clause altogether) is disregarded by this function.

2) `MATCH` with an exact (i.e. 0, or `FALSE`) *match_type* parameter is a relatively resource-heavy construction, particularly if the range to be considered is quite large. As such, and since it is not necessary to use this construction for `FREQUENCY`'s *bins_array* parameter, it is preferable to use the more efficient:

`ROW(tdata[reportUUID])-MIN(ROW(tdata[reportUUID]))+1`

Moreover, note that repetition of the `IF(LEN` construction is also not necessary within this second parameter.

In all, then:

`IF(FREQUENCY(IF(LEN(tdata[reportUUID])>0,MATCH(tdata[reportUUID],tdata[reportUUID],0)),ROW(tdata[reportUUID])-MIN(ROW(tdata[reportUUID]))+1)>0,TRUE)`

is considerably more rigorous and more efficient than the version you give.

To answer your main question, it is well-documented that `FREQUENCY` always returns an array having a number of entries one greater than that of the *bins_array* passed.

As mentioned in my comment to your post, the resolution to the problem you are facing largely depends on precisely what further manipulation you are intending for the resulting array.

However, let's assume for the sake of an explanation that you simply wish to multiply the array resulting from your `FREQUENCY` construction by some other column within your table, *tdata[Column2]* say, and then sum the result.

The difference between:

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(LEN(tdata[reportUUID])>0,MATCH(tdata[reportUUID],tdata[reportUUID],0)),ROW(tdata[reportUUID])-MIN(ROW(tdata[reportUUID]))+1)>0,TRUE)*tdata[Column2])`

i.e. using multiplication of the two arrays, and:

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(LEN(tdata[reportUUID])>0,MATCH(tdata[reportUUID],tdata[reportUUID],0)),ROW(tdata[reportUUID])-MIN(ROW(tdata[reportUUID]))+1)>0,tdata[Column2]))`

i.e. using a straightforward `IF` clause, is here crucial.

In fact, the former will always return an error, whereas the latter, in general, will not.

The reason is that the former will resolve to (assuming that your table has e.g. 10 rows' worth of data and assuming some random Boolean results to the `FREQUENCY` construction):

`=SUM(IF({TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE},TRUE)*tdata[Column2])`

which is, since the *value_if_true* clause is superfluous here:

`=SUM({TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE}*tdata[Column2])`

whereas the second construction I give will resolve to:

`=SUM(IF({TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE},tdata[Column2]))`

The two may look identical, but the fact that the former is using multiplication to resolve the array, whereas the latter is not, is the key difference.

Although in both cases the array resulting from the `FREQUENCY` construction, i.e.:

`{TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE}`

comprises 11 entries (i.e. 1 more than the number of entries in the second array being considered), the difference is that, when you then attempt to multiply an 11-element array with a 10-element array (i.e. *tdata[Column2]*), Excel, rather than outright disallowing such an operation, artificially redimensions the smaller of the two arrays such that it matches the dimensions of the larger.

In doing so, however, any additional entries are automatically set as `#N/A` error values.

Effectively, then:

`=SUM({TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE}*tdata[Column2])`

is resolved as:

`=SUM({TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE}*{38;67;49;3;10;11;97;20;3;57;#N/A})`

i.e., as mentioned, the second, 10-element array is redimensioned to one of 11 elements in an attempt to form a legitimate operation. And, as also mentioned, that 11th element is `#N/A`, which means of course that the entire construction will also result in that value.

In the non-multiplication version, however, i.e.:

`=SUM(IF({TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE},tdata[Column2]))`

although the same redimensiong also takes place, we are saved by our use of an `IF` clause in place of multiplication, since the above resolves to:

`=SUM(IF({TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE},{38;67;49;3;10;11;97;20;3;57;#N/A}))`

and the Boolean `FALSE` in the 11th position here 'overrides' the error value in the equivalent position from the second array, since the above resolves to:

`=SUM({38;FALSE;49;FALSE;10;11;97;FALSE;3;FALSE;FALSE})`

Regards

Comment: This is an amazing answer. Didn't know about the equivalent ROW() for this, great side tip. And super thorough.

Are there any circumstances where using products to combine multiple conditions like would be advisable, or is the construction as addition a genrally better approach? Other maybe than the fact that it is slighlty clunkier (and then that need not matter for re-usable criteria that I would wrap into name formulas anyways)?

I guess I'll start editing....

Comment: I understand that, In general, a nested IF statement resolves more efficiently than the equivalent construction which employs arithmetical operations (multiplication is not exclusive in this respect: typical criteria-based constructions involving AGGREGATE make use of division, for example). Of course, the fact that nested IF statements almost always require the construction to be committed with CSE might, by some, be considered a small downside, for example when compared to (where possible) a multiplicative SUMPRODUCT equivalent.

Comment: However, required keystroke combination aside, there really is nothing to be 'feared' in array formulas, not to mention the fact that SUMPRODUCT is itself no less an array formula than those which require CSE.